# watermark on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, photo, watermark

I am wondering if you can help me again.
I am having trouble with creating/putting a watermark on the profile images.

Till now I have:

WaterMarkController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Image;

class WaterMarkController extends Controller
{
    public function imageWatermark()
    {
        Image::make(public_path('storage/images/background.jpg'));

        /* insert watermark at bottom-right corner with 10px offset */
        $img->insert(public_path('storage/images/watermark.png'), 'bottom-right', 10, 10);
        $img->encode('png');

        $img->save(public_path('storage/images/new-image.png'));

        $type = 'png';
        $new_image = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($img);

        return view('show_watermark', compact('new_image'));
    }

    public function textWatermark()
    {
        Image::make(public_path('storage/images/background.jpg'));

        $img->text('MyNotePaper', 710, 370, function ($font) {
            $font->file(public_path('font/amandasignature.ttf'));
            $font->size(30);
            $font->color('#f4d442');
            $font->align('center');
            $font->valign('top');
            $font->angle(0);
        });

        $img->save(public_path('storage/images/new-image.png'));

        $img->encode('png');
        $type = 'png';
        $new_image = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($img);

        return view('show_watermark', compact('new_image'));
    }

}
```

The file -  show_watermark.blade.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Laravel Add Watermark on Images</title>
</head>
<body style="margin-top: 40px; text-align: center;">

<h1>Laravel Add Watermark</h1>

<img src="{{$new_image}}" alt="Watermark">

</body>
</html>
```

and the routes:

```
Route::get('watermark-image', 'WaterMarkController@imageWatermark');
Route::get('watermark-text', 'WaterMarkController@textWatermark');
```

what else should be done? Because I am having the error :

Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException
Image source not readable

How do I make it readable?
And nowhere in the code, I haven't shown the path to the image that I want for watermark (I have created my own logo for the project and I want to use it), how do I show the path to it?
And do I put it in the same place where the profile pictures are or, in another folder?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Can you try encode as **data-url** for $new_image ? http://image.intervention.io/api/encode

Comment: @Enver I am a little bit new to this, and I am not sure if I am doing the encoding right...
I have made it into the RuntimeException.php for the image:

<?PHP



namespace Intervention\Image\Exception;


class RuntimeException extends ImageException

{

    # nothing to override



    public function imageWatermark()

    {

    // encode png image as jpg

    $jpg = (string) Image::make('public/foo.png')->encode('jpg', 75);



    // encode image as data-url

    $data = (string) Image::make('public/bar.png')->encode('data-url');

   

 }
}

Comment: No, not into RuntimeException file. Try into your Controller: WaterMarkController

Comment: @Enver I tried it and it didn't work. The error is still the same, also there is another description in the code and it doesn't help too:         
        $new_image = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($img);

Comment: I am trying to figure out to what image the code is connected, as I am realizing that I haven't pointed any the path t my image, but I am not sure where and what to ut for that

Comment: is the image being saved on _images/new-image.png_?

Comment: Yes, it is saved there. Even when it didn't catch it I've made few copies on the folder on different places so I can try it and it still didn't worked

Comment: do you have images/background.png and images/watermark.png in public folder?

Comment: It worked when I use encode as data-url. Look at these: https://imgur.com/a/b7PmASP

Comment: Tried it, and still nothing. :D

Comment: Okay, don't bother it so much, I will find out. If not, I am gonna try to do something else. Maybe on another project, it will work.

Comment: Okay, you can debug line by line the $img object with `var_dump($img)` and figured out where your code broken.

Comment: amm... Not working. xD  But as I said, don't bother yourself with that. I have special powers to brake a lot of things when I touch them... XD  I had a choice to choose between few tasks and I choose this one because I have created the logo for that point, but I will take one of the other tasks.  Thank you very much and sorry for taking your time. I will try it on another project which I think that I am going to start soon.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what do you happen, maybe if your use Linux you need to add permissions to the public folder maybe, because on windows I create a project with your code and work perfectly, sure that you have the files on correct folders

```
public function imageWatermark()
    {
        $img = Image::make(public_path('images/background.jpg'));

        /* insert watermark at bottom-right corner with 10px offset */
        $img->insert(public_path('images/logo-dateado-blanco.png'), 'bottom-right', 10, 10);
        $img->encode('png');

        $img->save(public_path('images/new-image.png'));

        $type = 'png';
        $new_image = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($img);

        return view('show_watermark', compact('new_image'));
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am on windows 10. Am, the images are in the public->stprage->images.
Isn't that the right place for the folder, as I am using that place for the avatars pictures for the profile pictures, where actually I want' to put my watermark on, but first wanted to try if it even works (which for now is not working).  And I still have this error: Image source not readable

Comment: Hey but you said that you have the images on public->storage->images you need to use Image::make(public_path('storage/images/background.jpg'));

Comment: That's something that I wrote but it still doesn't fix the problem